# Sort-parametric wrapper functions

Tags: types, wrapper, z3, parametric-polymorphism

Assuming the use of several built-in and user defined Z3 sorts, e.g. Int, Bool, S1, S2, ..., is there a way of writing a generic sort-wrapping and -unwrapping function that kind of casts from sort A to sort B and back? For example

```
(declare-const a S1)
(declare-const b S2)
(declare-const c Int)

(WRAP[S1] b) ; Expression is of sort S1
(WRAP[S1] c) ; Expression is of sort S1
(WRAP[Int] (WRAP[S1] c)) ; Expression is of sort Int
```

I currently cover each case manually, e.g.

```
(declare-fun $boolToInt (Bool) Int)
(declare-fun $intToBool (Int) Bool)

(assert (forall ((x Int))
  (= x ($boolToInt($intToBool x)))))

(assert (forall ((x Bool))
  (= x ($intToBool($boolToInt x)))))
```

Such wrappers could be created automatically from a given set of sorts, but I would prefer a generic solution of possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use datatypes to encode "union types". 
Here is an example:

```
(declare-sort S1)
(declare-sort S2)

(declare-datatypes () ((S1-S2-Int (WRAP-S1 (S1-Value S1))
                                  (WRAP-S2 (S2-Value S2))
                                  (WRAP-Int (Int-Value Int)))))

(declare-const a S1)
(declare-const b S2)
(declare-const c Int)

(simplify (WRAP-S1 a))
(simplify (= (WRAP-S1 a) (WRAP-Int 10)))
(simplify (S1-Value (WRAP-S1 a)))
(simplify (is-WRAP-S2 (WRAP-S1 a)))
(simplify (is-WRAP-S1 (WRAP-S1 a)))
(simplify (is-WRAP-Int (WRAP-Int c)))
(simplify (S1-Value (WRAP-S2 b)))
```

You can find more information about datatypes in the [Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide). The datatype `S1-S2-Int` has three constructors: `WRAP-S1`, `WRAP-S2` and `WRAP-Int`. Z3 automatically generates the recognizer predicates: `is-WRAP-S1`, `is-WRAP-S2` and `is-WRAP-Int`. The accessors `S1-Value`, `S2-Value` and `Int-Value` are used to "deconstruct" a `S1-S2-Int` value. For example, for all `a`, `(S1-Value (WRAP-S1 a)) = a`. The value of `(S1-Value (WRAP-S2 b))` is underspecified. In this case, Z3 treats `S1-Value` as a uninterpreted function.

BTW, the axiom

```
(assert (forall ((x Int))
  (= x ($boolToInt($intToBool x)))))
```

is equivalent to false. It is essentially trying to inject the integers into the Booleans.

Comment: Thanks, Leo! I didn't notice that the $boolToInt axiom is equivalent to false, but it was luckily never triggered.

Your solution still requires creating a union datatype for all concerned sorts upfront, but I guess there is no way around that.